# how to console the requested url without console the static files urls in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an issue, this issue is i am trying to run simple node.js server i

this is y code

```js
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.url); 
});
```

the problem is I loaded HTML file and inside it, there are static files like CSS and javascript, the console output to me like this

```
/
/main.css
/main.js
```

but I want to console or get jus the first link not the links if static files

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. To me, you are mixing some kind of client Javascript (via the browser) and some Node.js (that is run via your server). I'd recommend you to read some of these many resources about how Node.js works.

Comment: What do you mean by "... just the first link?".  I'm going to guess that you need to install the Express npm package and write routes. A route being a URL pattern that your (node.js) web server will handle.

Comment: i don't mix a client code with node.js, and i am an express.js developer, but i wanna to make somthing with pure node.js without any npm package, 
my question is :
if i use fs module to load html file, and iside the html file i put <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
and served it wth node.js server with fs module successfully, my problem is
when i write console.log(req.url), it outputs the all urls included the url of static files, it out put 

/
/main.css
/favico.io
 what i wnat is console the first url and don't console the url of static files